# Where should flutter assets of flutterappB go if app is included in flutterappA as a package?

Tags: flutter

I'm assuming that we can have one flutter app embededded in another, for example if I have a reusable menu that has an image that I want to use in multiple apps.

So, FlutterAppA references FlutterAppB and is included in FlutterAppA's pubspec.yaml.  FlutterAppB includes the image in its asset folder, declared in the pubspec file and defines a widget that displays that asset.  I want to access that widget from B (displaying the widget with the asset)

B's pubspec

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/smile.gif
```

A's pubspec

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_app_b:
    path: ../flutter_app_b/
```

When B is run on its own the image is displayed.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
          home: SmileAssetImage());
}
class SmileAssetImage extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Image.asset('assets/smile.gif');
}
```

however when it is accessed in FlutterAppA it cannot find the asset and an 'unable to load Asset exception is thrown'.

Is the asset in the correct place, should it be in both asset folders and/or both pubspec folders?

Comment: in A's pubspec add `assets:
    - ../flutter_app_b/assets/smile.gif`

Comment: ah, I'm still getting the error, the pubspec compiles but I continue to get a runtime error when A tries to render the widget in B (asset unable to load exception).  If I remove the asset from B and include it in the normal way in A it does display in A but of course it is no longer working in B!

Comment: hmmm, now I can't seem to get anything working in flutter_app_b (after flutter clean too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, it seems like the assets should be included and declared in whichever app is actually run (if running A then the assets needs to be defined in app A, if running B then the assets need to be in app B).  The `flutter clean` command seemed to be necessary

Comment: if both the projects are in the same directory then you can save the asset in that directory and use as: `../smile.gif`